# Why the conditional formatting on bar chart disappear after I restart my excel workbook?

Tags: excel, bar-chart, conditional-formatting

[image]

I'm actually adding conditional formatting to the bar chart. So if the value is positive it will be green otherwise red. It works perfectly. However, when I restart my excel workbook, the red colour become white colour, leaving the positive green colour alone. Does anyone know what is the problem? The only possible reason that I can think of is this is a pivot chart, but I have no idea how to solve that. Please give some advice. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the "Invert if negative"-Option? Is it possible that you have "Automatic" selected under "Fill"? If you chose "Solid fill" and specify green as fill color and red as inverted fill color, those colors won't change after re-opening the workbook (at least not for me).

Comment: Are you using pivot chart? Becuase I'm using pivot chart and I choose green colour for "solid fill" and red for " invert if negative", it will go back to default  "Automatic" after I restart my workbook. I edited my question with new screenshot.

Comment: Yes, now I could reproduce your problem. There's some articles that describe how to preserve formatting in Pivot Charts, one is to right-click on chart, PivotChart Options, check "Preserve cell formatting on update". However, that doesn't solve your specific problem... I ran out of ideas! Hope you find the answer.